# Text wrapping in .docx output of flextable in r-markdown

Tags: r-markdown, docx, pandoc, flextable, officer

I have a r-markdown doc that has a flextable that spreads over multiple pages and on my own computer it knits to docx. perfectly. However, now it is on the server and it automated the knitted document has the table on a new page. This can be manually changed in the outputted word doc by changing "text wrapping" to "Around" in "table Properties" menu. This is workable but as these docs are automated, I would like the format to be correct from the begininng. Any ideas on how to force the table to stay on the first page with the headings??
** I should add that saving the table properties in the reference doc does not seem to help.

Cheers
Silas

Answer (score 1):

I asked the author of the `flextable` package a similar question. He suggested I change the knitr chunk option `ft.keepnext` to `FALSE` and it worked for me.

````
```{r, ft.keepnext = FALSE}

myflextable

```
````